# Apagar formulário de cadastro, JSF Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, formulário

Estou usando `JSF` com `primefaces`. Eu tenho uma tela de cadastro, e tenho um botão para apagar os dados do formulário, seria um botão para limpar o formulário para fazer um outro cadastro.
Porém, esse botão de limpar não está funcionando. Gostaria de pedir uma ajuda.

Código da página:

```html
 <h:form id="formUser">         
          <p:messages id="messages" />            
           <p:panelGrid id ="panelGrid" columns="2" style="horizontal-align:center">           
                  <p:outputLabel for="id" value="ID:" />
                  <p:spinner id="id" value="#{UsuarioMB.usuario.id}" />
                   
                  <p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />
                  <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{UsuarioMB.usuario.nome}" />                   
                     
                  <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha:" />
                  <p:inputText id="senha" value="#{UsuarioMB.usuario.senha}" />  
                  
                  <p:outputLabel for="descricao" value="Descrição:" />
                  <p:inputTextarea id="descricao" value="#{UsuarioMB.usuario.descricao}" /> 
                  
         <p:outputLabel for="dataCadastro" value="DataCadastro:" />
                      <p:calendar value="#{UsuarioMB.usuario.dataCadastro}" locale="pt_BR"
             id="dataCadastro" showButtonPanel="true">
           <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
         </p:calendar>            
            
                <p:commandButton id="insert"  value="Cadastrar"   action= "#{UsuarioMB.cadastraUsuario}"   update="userTabela,:formUser"   >
                   </p:commandButton> 
                    <p:commandButton  value="Consultar" icon="ui-icon-star"  action= "#{UsuarioMB.consultar}"   update="userTabela"   >
                    </p:commandButton> 
                    <p:commandButton  value="Limpar"  action= "#{UsuarioMB.limpar}"  update=":formUser"  type="reset"    >
                   </p:commandButton> 
            </p:panelGrid> 
             
      <p:dataTable id="userTabela" var="usuario" value="#{UsuarioMB.lista}"
  paginator="true" rows="10" emptyMessage="Não há registros na lista"
  paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
  rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,25,50,100"  rowKey="#{usuario.id}" selection="#{usuario}" selectionMode="single" > 
  <f:facet name="header">Lista de usuários</f:facet> 
       <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{UsuarioMB.onRowSelect}" update=":formUser" /> 
       
  <p:column headerText="ID" style="width: 10%;" sortBy="#{usuario.id}"  >
     <h:outputText value="#{usuario.id}" />  
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Nome" style="width: 25%;" sortBy="#{usuario.nome}"> 
               <h:outputText value="#{usuario.nome}" />  
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Descrição" style="width: 25%;" sortBy="#{usuario.descricao}">
   <h:outputText value="#{usuario.descricao}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Data de Cadastro" style="width: 25%;" sortBy="#{usuario.dataCadastro}">
   <h:outputText value="#{usuario.dataCadastro}" />
  </p:column>    
 </p:dataTable>              
   </h:form>
```

Código java:

```html
     public void limpar() {
   System.out.println("Limpar");
   System.out.println(usuario);
   usuario = new Usuario();
   setUsuario(usuario); 
  }
        
     public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) { 
      this.usuario = usuario;
     }
```

Obrigado galera.

Comment: Era pra funcionar do jeito que você implementou. Como aparece a tela depois de pressionar o limpar? Tenta dar um F5 depois de pressionar ele pra ver se é problema no reRender do ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer este botão de limpar somente para apagar os dados ou depois do inserir os dados a tela deve ser limpa para novos dados? Se o caso for para limpar depois de inserir, não fica melhor você automatizar este processo? No metodo cadastraUsuario você coloca um setUsuario(new Usuario) e daí depois de cadastrar ele vai limpar os dados automaticamente e com o update já limpa a ela. Agora se é somente para limpar os dados, tente usar no botão Limpar process="@this".

Comment: Ele pode também ao invés de setar um novo usuário, colocar usuario = null;

Answer (score 1):

Para simplificar, você pode setar o usuário para null, como no exemplo abaixo e alterar seu update no xhtml:

```
public void limpar() {
        usuario = null;
    }


<p:commandButton  value="Limpar"  action= "#{UsuarioMB.limpar}"  update="@this"  type="reset"    >
                   </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Se colocar ele pra null vai dar nullpointer porque o formulário chama dados desse objeto sem testar a nulidade. Tem que ser um "new Usuario()" mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado gente, todas as dicas funcionaram.
Eu fiz assim.

```html
  <p:commandButton  value="Limpar"  action= "#{UsuarioMB.limpar}"  update=":formUser"   process="@this"  >
                   </p:commandButton>
```

```html
 if (dao.insertUsuario(usuario)) {
                     setUsuario(new Usuario());
                 listar(); 
                     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                               null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Sucesso! Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!", "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!"));
                }
```

Agradeço a ajuda, ;)